# how to know densitybytes in print with esc pos?

Tags: flutter

i am having image quality related problem after printing with xt423 printer.
I learn the following inside the esc_pos_utils library. And there is a confusion about how densityByte is calculated: Why is it only 0 or 33.

Is there any relevant documentation that explains this?

Help me.

```
   final int heightPx = imageRotated.height;

    int densityByte =
        (highDensityHorizontal ? 1 : 0) + (highDensityVertical ? 32 : 0);

    final List<int> header = List.from(cBitImg.codeUnits);
    header.add(densityByte);
    header.addAll(_intLowHigh(heightPx, 4));

    // Adjust line spacing (for 16-unit line feeds): ESC 3 0x10 (HEX: 0x1b 0x33 0x10)
    bytes += [27, 51, 0];
    for (int i = 0; i < blobs.length; ++i) {
      bytes += List.from(header)
        ..addAll(blobs[i])
        ..addAll('\n'.codeUnits);
    }
    // Reset line spacing: ESC 2 (HEX: 0x1b 0x32)
    bytes += [27, 50];
```